# Is a comma necessary here?

Tags: commas

Can I insert a comma in this sentence like this:

"Consequently, the type of the vehicle they are using can be specified as well as if they are walking or stationary somewhere."

Or is the sentence better without it:

"Consequently the type of the vehicle they are using can be specified as well as if they are walking or stationary somewhere."

Comment: Well, the first is a definite no-go.  The second is *a little* better.

Comment: Keep the commas after _consequently_ and before _as well as_

Comment: And you absolutely must get rid of the one after "vehicle". It is totally out of place and destroys the sense of the phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write:

> Consequently, the type of vehicle they are using can be specified, as well as whether they are walking or stationary somewhere.

The commas aren't technically required, but they help the reader see the structure of the sentence. When a sentence has a number of subordinate clauses, this is usually a good idea to make it easier to read.

And *whether* tends to be a better word than *if* when stating alternate options.

Comment: For consistency with "walking", I wouldn't use just "stationary".  I would prefer "...whether they are walking or staying stationary somewhere."

Comment: I don't think that's necessary. _walking_ is a gerund that can be used in parallel with an adjective.

Comment: As another example, you can say _whether they are moving or stopped_.

Comment: Their mere existence implies that they have a location, so the 'somewhere' is superfluous.